# Should I follow the database entities in creating models in angular?

Tags: angular, frontend, angular7

I have two tables:

> **`users`**
>
> **`users_information`**

The **users** table has entities of id, username, and passwords.

The **users_information** table has an address, images, age, etc.

They are separated by purpose.

I am using angular in front end and laravel in my back end.
When requesting and API, this information or two tables are combine.

Should I construct my angular models the same as my database models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should construct your DTO models based on the API response regradless the database relations.

So you can combine user and user information in one DTO model as it is in the API response.

API role is to combine the information and prepare it for you, then you map it as it is.